# Creating portable class library in VS2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, portable-class-library

Good morning,
I'm new to cross-platform programming, so I have a very basic question. I wanted to use `Xamarin` to create an app for all mobile platforms + desktop versions for mac and windows. I wanted to use Visual Studio 2015. I got stuck at the very start. I wanted to create `Class Library (portable)`, but as I can see, there are few such projects. [Here is the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eKJ6.png)

My question is: What's the difference between those 5 projects?

There are:

**Class Library (Portable)** *A project for creating a managed class library (.dll) for Windows, Windows Phone and Silverlight apps.*

**Blank App (Native Portable)** *A multiproject template for building cross-platform native apps, sharing code using a portable class library. On Visual Studio 2010, the Portable Class Library Tools are required.*

**Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable)** *A multiproject template for building apps with Xamarin.Forms, sharing code using a portable class library. On Visual Studio 2010, the Portable Class Library Tools are required.*

**Class Library (Xamarin.Forms Portable)** *A portable class library for creating shared application code using Xamarin.Forms. On Visual Studio 2010, the Portable Class Library Tools are required.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Class Library (Portable) - this is just a PCL project [not sure why it's listed twice]
- Blank App (Native Portable) - will create a project for each available platform AND a PCL library for shared code
- Blank App (Forms Portable) - will create a project for each platform, and a PCL library for shared code.  Will also install the Forms packages and templates
- Class Library (Forms Portable) - will create just the PCL project with the Forms packages and templates

you probably want to use the first option

Comment: Thanks for answer, I removed repeated content. I have two questions:

What kind of PCLs are created, while creating Blank App with or without Forms packages? While creating Blank App, Visual Studio is not asking me what kind of PCL I want to create (what should be included...)

Second question, Can I create regular PCL (first option) and later add "Forms packages and templates"?

Comment: By default, I believe it creates Profile 78, which is iOS/Android/4.5.  Yes, you can add the Forms packages separately, the project template is just for convenience.